# Undefined Text in OQL picker

Tags: ewam

Why does a row appear are as 'undefined text' in the results of an OQL picker search? I have added a string extract.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvy3R.png)

Comment: You need to explain more and tell us what you expected to be

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have same number of fields in OQL select and OQL fetch. If there is a mismatch in the number of fields, you will get the 'undefined text' in the results of an QOL.

Comment: Yes, thank you that worked. I had a select * but was fetching just 3 columns. This mismatch caused the error.